# How do we find $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Square $\text {ABCD}$ has side length 6 and the side AB is parallel to the x-axis. The points A, B, and C are on $y = \log_a(x), y = 2 \log_a(x)$, and $y = 3 \log_a(x)$ respectively.

[image]

- Then, how do we find $a$?

This question is forced me. Might I get your thinkings?

Comment: Hint:  define $x_0$ by saying $B$ has coordinates $(x_0,2\log_a(x_0))$.  Now write down the coordinates of $A,C$ in terms of $x_0$.

Comment: Note:  this question has nothing to do with either complex-analysis nor least-squares.

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to work out your hint now. Which tag do i need use? Could you edit my question?

Comment: I added the logarithms tag, left in pre-calculus.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot. It seems better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let's call the $x$ value of $A$ $x_A$.
So $y_A=\log_a(x_A)$, therefore you have $y_B=2\log_a(x_A-6)$ and $y_C=3\log_a(x_A-6)$ and you know $y_C-y_B=6$ and $y_A=y_B$.